# Azure Data Factory copy activity JSON data type conversion issue

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have an azure data factory pipeline for fetch the data from a third party API and store the data to the data-lake as .json format. When i click the import schema, it shows the correct datatype format.
[image]

When I set the above mentioned data-lake as a source of data flow activity, the Int64 data type convert to boolean. I have checked the Microsoft documents and knew if the value is 0 or 1, it automatically convert to boolean. How can I avoid this data type conversion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify if you have checked 'Infer drifted column types' to true under Source Settings.

Data Factory detects the data type as boolean if the values in the source column are only 1 or 0. This could be a potential bug.

One way around is, since you are using Data Flow, Add derivations for the columns using a Case statement and derive 1 & 0 in output based on boolean value.

Comment: Hi GRT, Thanks for your quick response. You are right, we can do with derived column in data flow. But the thing is, if any values there instead of 0 or 1, the derived column expression may error, right?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is that just reset the all schema to String, that means don't convert the data type in Source dataset.

For example, this my source dataset schema and data, all the values in `setNum` are 1 or 0:
[image]

Data Flow Source Projection, the data type of setNum first considered as Boolean.

[image]

Reset schema: all the data type will be string.

[image]

Then data factory will convert the data type in Sink level. It is similar with copy data from csv file.

Update:

You can first reset the schema to String.

Then using [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to change/convert the data type as you want.

Using bellow expressions:

```
toShort()
toString()
toShort()
```

[image]

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Leon, Thanks for the response. In this situation all fields will be considered as string. I don't want to change the data types.

Comment: @SyamKumar, actually, that won't change the data type. As we know, all the data type in a flat file is string. If you don't reset schema, the Data preview also has error in Data Flow. Data factory will convert the data to suitable data type and mapping to Sink in backend.

Comment: Data preview has no error. If I reset the schema, the output will be like
replies_count : "0"
rank : "1235"
If the datatype is integer it should show like 
rank : 1234

Comment: @SyamKumar Reset the schema to String first and then using Derived Column to reset the data type. I updated my answer, hope you can understand it clearly. In usually, that's the best way for us.

Comment: That works. But I am working with complex array, Inside the array, there are lot of objects and child arrays. All the fields need to be change and that will be pain for me. Also, if any new fields added in the array, I should update the derived column, right?

Comment: @SyamKumar yes, derived column also get the input from source.

Comment: Per my experience, we usually do not need to convert all the columns, such as String to String. Only set the column which we need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218196/discussion-between-syam-kumar-and-leon-yue).

Comment: Hi @SyamKumar, do you have any other questions?

Comment: Hi @SyamKumar, hope you're doing well. If the answer is helpful for you, really hope you can accept it as answer This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much, please.

Comment: Hi @Leon, the answer was not satisfying.It's only a work around and I can't do this way. I have created a derived column and created new object with same name based on the boolean value. The expression is like

@(replies_count=case(toString(thread.replies_count)=='false',0,
toString(thread.replies_count)=='true',1,toInteger(toString(thread.replies_count))).

 I have done the work around and it is matched with second answer. I can give the upvote for your answer and thank you.